# Rails functional minitest for controller action that happens to send an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, testunit

When I `assert_template` after calling an action that also sends out an email I'm getting the email template information instead of the one showed in the browser.

**The controller action**

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params)
    if @user.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user), :notice => "User Created" }
      end
    end
end
```

The `@user.save` method have a callback that **sends a confirmation email** to the user.

**The test**

```
  test 'should render show template' do
    post :create, user: {:email => 'test@example.com'}
    assert_template :show  # Here I'm getting the email template that is being sent on after save callback
  end
```

How can I assert that the browsing user is being correctly redirected to the (user) **show** action?

Comment: Did you try `assert_redirected_to(user)` instead of assert_template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `assert_redirected_to`

```
 test 'should render show template' do
    post :create, user: {:email => 'test@example.com'}
    assert_redirected_to(user_path(assigns(:user))
 end
```

Comment: To be exact it should be: `assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))`